# Class 'String' has no instance getter 'isNegative'. in flutter

Tags: flutter

Class 'String' error has no instance getter 'isNegative' when specifying price format. Displays

```dart
Widget _cartRow(int index) {

    var priceFormat = NumberFormat("###,###", "fa_IR");
    String price = priceFormat.format(product_data[index]['price'].toString()) + "toman";


    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 20,top: 10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10,top: 5,bottom: 5),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.white,offset: Offset(5.0,5.0),)],
    ),
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          children: [
          Expanded(child: Image(alignment: Alignment.centerRight,height: 100,image: NetworkImage(AppData.server_url + product_data[index]['img_url']))),
          Expanded(child: Text(product_data[index]['title'],textAlign: TextAlign.right,)),
          /*Expanded(child: Text(product_data[index]['number'].toString(),textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)))*/
        ],),
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey.shade100,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Row(children: [
            const Expanded(child: Text("price product:",textAlign: TextAlign.right,)),
            Expanded(child: Text(price,textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red.shade600),)),
          ],),
        )
      ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In this method the 'String' error has no instance getter 'isNegative'. is shown
And is related to the price line format code

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to use String in the `format` function as it checks for the `isNaN`.

You need to pass a number (double or int or num) instead.

```dart
var priceFormat = NumberFormat("###,###", "fa_IR");
String price = priceFormat.format(123) + "toman";
```

In `format` add the actual price instead of the **123** in your case it will be `product_data[index]['price']`.

Comment: The actual price is inside product_data [index] ['price']

Comment: If it is a number you can simply pass it to the format() and it will work.